# How to install app using BlackBerry Enterprise Server?

Tags: blackberry

[image]

can you please tell me the steps .How to install my app using BES (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
I have only code and alx file.
[image]

From where i will download BES server ..

Comment: Before answering, I recommend readers review the similar question asked in the BB forum.  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-install-app-using-BlackBerry-Enterprise-Server/td-p/2787465

Comment: I don't get from that

Comment: Please give me necessary steps as I am beginner in BES .I just want to install my app using BES

Comment: My original comment was not intended for you, it was intended for anyone intending to answer, to point out that the problem had moved on.  Given your last comment, can you please answer the question - WHY?

Comment: Thanks peter can you please give me address so that i will download

Comment: Because Using BES application don't use url (access) .we submit information on BES server then we will intall app without url access

Comment: any help will be thankfull to all

Comment: Can you please explain clearly in your question (not in a comment) why you HAVE to install using BES and can't install using any of the other options available to you, as documented here:  http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/25767/Methods_to_install_BB_Java_Apps_629138_11.jsp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47856/discussion-between-user944513-and-peter-strange)

Comment: Continued in BB forum rather than chat.